# Regex after position until end of line

Tags: regex

I have a string:

```
Update [dbo].[User] SET  [UserPOId]=('6a26f3ad-e211-12ea-a258-1136b811e586', '111b37f8-5ecb-1653-8671-e7121d8de811', 'iaridhuet@dsasfd.de', 'dasfsad3zQ', 'Inad', 'HRauch', 'ingfdasfa@ds.de', '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111', '577b618c-f316-1dda-a2f6-1f25bcfe11eb')

Update [dbo].[User] SET  [UserPOId]=('6a26f3ad-e211-12ea-a258-1136b811e586', '111b37f8-5ecb-1653-8671-e7121d8de811', 'isdfasdf@sdfad.de', 'dasfsad3zQ', 'Inad', 'HRauch', 'ingfdasfa@ds.de', '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111', '577b618c-f316-1dda-a2f6-1f25bcfe11eb')
```

Now I need all characters after position *129*, but with my regex I get only the first match, but I need the thing which wil come after:

`^.{129}`

How to do ?

Comment: Use a `.*` in a capturing group: [`^.{129}(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/qW0yK0/1) and the text will be in Group 1. What is the tool/programming language/regex library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=^.{129}).*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/uN0iY0/1

**Explanation:**

The lookbehind `(?<=^.{129})` before `.*` will ensure your pattern `.*` is preceded by 129 chars (`.{129}`) from start (`^`).

Comment: That is a positive lookbehind.

Comment: @AnshulRai, Oh, yes, sure. Thank you for pointing out. Fixed.